# Layout for device with same resolution but different screen size in android

Tags: android, layout

I have to add two layout for two different device both with same resolution but different screen size. Since both are taking the same layout i.e. hdpi. If i am trying to change text size for one device it becomes smaller for the device with smaller screen size.

Comment: What is your layout folder name?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting your text size in px, this is not the way to do it, but use sp.

Take a look at this disscussion about the advantaces of dp and sp.

[android layout at different screen sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25558176/android-layout-at-different-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 0):

You can define different size in `dimen.xml` file of different size `value` folder

Comment: I did that. But there are some devices that have same resolution but their screen size varies due to this some of the text that fits the screen becomes larger for other devices with same resolution but smaller display size.